# collation error when retrieving arabic names from sql server via php

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have an SQL server db, and i wanna retrieve info from it using PHP, i use this code which shows Arabic names as question marks as the following pic.

```
<?php
  $serverName = "10.0.0.5";
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"academy", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"123");

   /* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users;';
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

   echo '<pre>';
   while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
         print_r($r);
   }
?>
```

[image: Arabic names appear as question marks]

So, how can i make it appear as Arabic given that my DB collation is Arabic_CI_CS and i tried to change the browser encoding and putting meta tag with different character sets but in vain!

Answer (score 0):

i think every thing is going fine with your database connection and fetching  data. you just need to set your character set in your webpage and as-well-as in you webpage

for your database you have to make your field character code "UTF8-general-ci"

for your webpage try to add meta tag...

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

it should workk fine..

worked well for me...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"SomeDB", "UID"=>"SomeUser", "PWD"=>"SomePWD",'CharacterSet'=>'UTF-8');
```

the solution is adding CharacterSet = utf-8